# iOS : detect UIWebView reaching the top or bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

How can I detect UIWebView reaching the top or bottom? 
Because I need to trigger an action when I reach the bottom.

So is that doable?

Comment: You should consider approving an answer if there is one that works for you

Answer (score 27):

First of all, you should not put your `UIWebView` inside a `UIScrollView` as mentionned in the `UIWebView` documentation.

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Instead, you can access the `UIScrollView` through the `UIWebView` properties. Your view controller can implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

Then you can hook to the UIScrollView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set self as scroll view protocol
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
}
```

Then finally detect the top and bottom being reached:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y 
       >= 
       (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)){
        NSLog(@"BOTTOM REACHED");
    }
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0.0){
        NSLog(@"TOP REACHED");
    }
}
```

Voila, you can detect when top and bottom are reached.

Comment: Consider using KVO on the `contentOffset` property of the child `scrollView` instead. It doesn't have to be safe to modify the delegate property of the `UIScrollView` since `UIWebView` can be using it internally.

Answer (score 3):

You can give this a shot -

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == yourWebView)
    {
        int percentScrolled = abs((int)ceil((scrollView.contentOffset.y/scrollView.contentSize.height)*100));
        if(percentScrolled > 100 || percentScrolled < 0)
            percentScrolled = 0;

        if(percentScrolled > 90)
        {
            //scroll percent is 90. do your thing here.
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

What is being done here is everytime user scrolls webView, calculate the % scrolled & when the % scrolled is coming to end (say anything > 90%) do whatever you planned to do.

Comment: i tried it but the delegate method does not get called at all :(

Comment: Nope, UIWebView doesn't inherit from UIScrollView. It surely uses one inside, but exposes it only as of iOS 5.

Comment: @MohamedEmadHegab They are trying to help you. My general understanding of "corrected my answer" is that: Yes, it should work... not what??

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting iOS 5, `UIWebView` has a read-only `scrollView` property that allows you to access the underlying `UIScrollView`.

From there, you can hook into the scrollView's `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method to receive information on scroll events.

Answer (score 1):

*You could put UIWebView inside a UIScrollView (that has bouncing disabled, so the bounce behavior of the views does not conflict in any way) and then when UIWebView scrolls to bottom, the UIScrollView above will take over scrolling and you can listen to its scrolling events.*

### Scratch that.

Seems that it's not that simple after all.

You can find the UIScrollView among UIWebView's subviews and tap into its scroll delegate methods.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"We scrolled! Offset now is %f, %f", scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *view = (UIWebView *)self.view;

    for (UIView * subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            UIScrollView *webScrollView = (UIScrollView *)subview;
            webScrollView.delegate = self;
            break;
        }
    }

    [view loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]]];
}
```

As the UIWebView loads the web content, its UIScrollView should change its contentSize property. You can use that to determine whether you're at the bottom or at the top already or not.

Comment: Not a good idea -- "**Important** You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled." -- [UIWebView docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: If you do it carefully, nothing will happen. Mobile Safari doesn't seem to have that problem - when you scroll to top, the address bar appears. I'll try to implement something similar and let you know how it went.

Comment: well it gave me error 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView loadRequest:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x879bc60'

Comment: Have you set view controller's view to UIWebView?

Answer (score 1):

You could use KVO to detect any change in the `contentOffset` property of your `UIWebView` instance.

Warning : Be careful because this property is changing very often when scrolling, and the events in the example below will pop really frequently. Don't implement or call high cost function at each contentOffset change !

Here is a code example for doing it in a `UIView` subclass containing a `UIWebView` :

```
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.scrollView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", options: [.New, .Old], context: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        webView.scrollView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        guard let kp = keyPath else {
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
            return
        }
        if kp == "contentOffset" {
            self.scrollViewDidScroll(webView.scrollView)
        } else {
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y - scrollView.frame.size.height < 100 {
            print("this is the end")
        } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 100 {
            print("this is the beginning")
        }
    }
```

As documented by Apple in UIWebview documentation, you should avoid placing your UIWebview instance in a UIScrollView to detect the end/beginning of scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Wkwebview:**

I am bit late, I implemented delegate of wkwebview to check scrollview reaches on top or bottom.I used to read javascript code through **evaluateJavaScript** function. Before use set scrollview delegate of your webview and implement **scrollViewDidEndDragging** delegate function of UIScrollViewDelegate

```
extension BaseWebViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView,
                                   willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
    if complete != nil {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
            let bodyScrollHeight = height as! CGFloat
            var bodyoffsetheight: CGFloat = 0
            var htmloffsetheight: CGFloat = 0
            var htmlclientheight: CGFloat = 0
            var htmlscrollheight: CGFloat = 0
            var wininnerheight: CGFloat = 0
            var winpageoffset: CGFloat = 0
            var winheight: CGFloat = 0

            //body.offsetHeight
            self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight", completionHandler: { (offsetHeight, error) in
                bodyoffsetheight = offsetHeight as! CGFloat

                self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.offsetHeight", completionHandler: { (offsetHeight, error) in
                    htmloffsetheight = offsetHeight as! CGFloat

                    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.clientHeight", completionHandler: { (clientHeight, error) in
                        htmlclientheight = clientHeight as! CGFloat

                        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (scrollHeight, error) in
                            htmlscrollheight = scrollHeight as! CGFloat

                            self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.innerHeight", completionHandler: { (winHeight, error) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    wininnerheight = -1
                                } else {
                                    wininnerheight = winHeight as! CGFloat
                                }

                                self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.pageYOffset", completionHandler: { (winpageOffset, error) in
                                    winpageoffset = winpageOffset as! CGFloat

                                    let docHeight = max(bodyScrollHeight, bodyoffsetheight, htmlclientheight, htmlscrollheight,htmloffsetheight)

                                    winheight = wininnerheight >= 0 ? wininnerheight : htmloffsetheight
                                    let winBottom = winheight + winpageoffset
                                    if (winBottom >= docHeight) {
                                        print("end scrolling")
                                    } else if winpageoffset == 0 {
                                            print("top of webview")
                                        }
                                })

                            })

                        })

                    })

                })
            })


        })
    }

})

}
}
```