# Move UIView along with UIWebView ala iPhone Chrome Browser

Tags: ios, google-chrome, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

On Chrome for iPhone the address bar and back button slide up and out of the way when dragging.  I would like to do something similar.  I've tried adding some gesture recognizers but can't quite duplicate the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15841830/467209

Basically: myWebView.scrollView.delegate = self;